# android AutoCompleteText View drop down hiding behind the keyboard

Tags: java, android

I have Been Using **AutoCompleteTextView** in an **alertDialog** and the dropDown is hiding behind the KeyBoard.
The **DropDown** should show upward so that user can select from that list.
How To Do It.

i am using like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Select District/Town*"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/textInput2"
    >
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/auto2"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

in java

```
    String[] courseList = new String[]{
        "BE/B-Tech", "M-Tech","B.sc","M.sc"
};

ArrayAdapter<String> courseListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProfileActivity.this,R.layout.activity_dropdownlistitems,R.id.list_item,courseList);

AutoCompleteTextView selectDistrict = (AutoCompleteTextView)alertDailogView.findViewById(R.id.auto2);

selectDistrict.setAdapter(courseListAdapter);
```

[image]

Comment: Add your layout to scrollView

Comment: Post your code for better understanding. If you post like this, probably your question will be taken down

Comment: i have edited the question and added code please check